# [cakePHP3]how to debug a failed save

Tags: debugging, save, cakephp-3.0

This is my code , I have problems with making a simple save. The message is :( when i trying to save

```
$user = $this->Users->newEntity();        
    if($this->request->is('post'))
    {                     
        $user = $this->Users->patchEntity($user, $this->request->data);    

        if($this->Users->save($user))
        {
            $this->Flash->success(':)');
            return $this->redirect(['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'index']);
        }
        else
        {                
            $this->Flash->error(':(');

        }
        debug($this->request->data);             
    }
    $this->set(compact('user'));
```

this is my table , I made a migration. All fields can be null

```
 $table = $this->table('users');
    $table->addColumn('first_name','string',array('limit'=>100))
          ->addColumn('last_name','string',array('limit'=>100))
          ->addColumn('email','string',array('limit'=>100))
            ->addColumn('password','string')
            ->addColumn('role','enum',array('values'=>'admin,user'))
            ->addColumn('active','boolean')
            ->addColumn('created','datetime')
            ->addColumn('modified','datetime')
            ->create();
```

this is my request data

```
[
'first_name' => 'wewe',
'last_name' => 'wewe',
'email' => 'wewe@wee.com',
'password' => 'wewewe',
'role' => 'admin',
'active' => '1'
```

]

I hope that you help me , I am very frustrated

EDIT:  if i use print_r ($user->errors()); i get this...

```
Array ( [firts_name] => Array ( [_required] => This field is required ) )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is in the name of your data, the request data is

> 'first_name' => 'wewe'"

your column name is "**firts**_name", its a typing error.

Comment: Good catch typo :)